# Creating tables with fields from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to group data from the following three tables to create a new table. the `account_no` fields in `bmf` and `acct_map` are actually drawn from `cmf`.

Fields:

```
bmf: account_no, trans_date
cmf: account_no, balance_due
acct_map: account_no, external_id
```

The fields I want in my new table are :

```
external_id, account_no, balance_due
```

When I use query 1, without the `external_id` column, it works fine and populates the data correctly. But when I try query 2, it creates a blank table. Why is this happening?

Query 1:

```
create table paid as
select bmf.account_no, sum(cmf.balance_due) postpaid_balance
from bmf, cmf
where to_char(bmf.trans_date, 'YYYY MM DD') = '1996 08 14' and
bmf.account_no = cmf.account_no
group by bmf.account_no
```

Query 2:

```
create table paid as
select bmf.account_no, sum(cmf.balance_due) postpaid_balance, acct_map.external_id
from bmf, cmf, acct_map
where to_char(bmf.trans_date, 'YYYY MM DD') = '1996 08 14' and
bmf.account_no = cmf.account_no and
acct_map.account_no = bmf.account_no
group by bmf.account_no, acct_map.external_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running your select query only first? I am guessing there is no account_no in table acct_map which is matching with account_no in bmf or cmf. Please check as your query seems to be fine so looks like a data issue.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan, it was a data population problem as you pointed out. Works well now. thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is an `inner join`, so I'm guessing that there are no records from Query 1 that share an `account_no` with `acct_map`.

You can quickly test this with the following query:

```
select count(*)
from
    acct_map
where
    account_no in (select bmf.account_no
            from bmf, cmf
            where to_char(bmf.trans_date, 'YYYY MM DD') = '1996 08 14' and
            bmf.account_no = cmf.account_no)
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I stand corrected. Thanks for pointing out. The acct_map and query1 do have accounts in common. infact the acct_map table has a list of all the accounts in the db. I'm only trying to query accounts for which payment has been processed and get the corresponding external id's in my new table. 

Any suggestions on how the query can be modified ?

Answer (score 0):

Eric is right, but let me add... shouldn't this be a view instead of moving data around?